# Onepage-Scroll not working in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mozilla

I am using the plugin OnePage Scroll by peachananr to make my site a one-page scrollable site.  I am running into issues with the mouse wheel events in Firefox specifically, which is making my site navigation break.  Specifically I can only scroll up.  Does anybody know how to fix this issue?  There doesn't seem to be any specific errors on the console.

Thank you!

Plugin site:  https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll

My site:  http://bmgzstrategies.com/new_site/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this issue was caused by some interactions between two plugins I was using.  I deleted one of the plugins and the issue was solved.  Thanks!